# C++ Sockets Unsynched/Parallel Code without Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have this 2-side(client and server) program written in c++, which is basically a "chat program".

So one side sends data to the other side which sends data to the other side .
I am using C-Sockets (TCP/SOCK_STREAM).

So my Problem is, that while the server is waiting for data ("recv()") it is unable to send data itself, as the recv queue is infinite, as far as my experience shows.

I have thought of two ways to solve this, but I am not sure if its worth the time. Because there maybe is a simple solution, which I am just too stupid too think of.

1. Make it a 6-sided connection, meaning I have a "physical Server", where my server is running on in four instances, twice for each client(sending and recieving). so if one server recieves data it stores the data in a file, for the sending server of the other client to read out and.. send it. Works same the other way around.

As this solution sounds rather shitty, I might not go with it.

2. Using Multithreading. Which is as I have heard pure cancer to use and you shouldn't use it, unless you have to.

So my question is, do I have to? or is there maybe a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

[recv()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) on a blocking socket is used when you need to wait for incoming data and have nothing to do until data is arrived. If it's not your case you can use [non-blocking socket](https://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html), or [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) with timeout. `select` would be simpler, just check if anything arrived on your socket regularly (e.g. in a loop), and do what you want in between.

By the way, it's called "BSD socket", not "C socket", this can help you googling.

Comment: Consider using `epoll()` instead of `select()` on platforms that support it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: you're right. Actually I don't use any of them (directly) and prefer cross-platform high level solutions like Boost.Asio